# How to handle Maps on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, map

Can anyone please help me to understand the below code. I am not able to understand how we are  extracting value from map on visualforce page.

Actually i am trying to get the size of value list which is associated with respective key in map.

```
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:repeat value="{!attributeWrapper.mapAllAttributesLabel}" var="M">
                    <div>
                        <div>{!attributeWrapper.mapLabels[M].Name} </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!attributeWrapper.mapAllAttributesLabel[M]}" var="attribute">
                                    <li>
                                    <p>
                                        <apex:outputLink onclick="selectAttribute('{!attribute.attributeLabel.Label__c}','{!attribute.attributeLabel.Attribute__c}');return false;">
                                           <apex:outputLabel value="{!attribute.attributeLabel.Attribute__r.Name}"/>
                                        </apex:outputLink>
                                    </p>
                                    </li>
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:outputPanel>



public with sharing class AttributeWrapper {
     public Map<String, List<AttributesLabelWrapper>> mapAllAttributesLabel{
      // some code to populate this map
    }
}
```

If i do:

```
{!attributeWrapper.mapAllAttributesLabel[M].size}
```

I get an error so how do i get the size of value list on VF page?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tried to replicate your problem, and ended up trying different things, no luck doing it your way (confirmed that, got a visualforce error), no luck with `<apex:param>` but what I ended up doing was I created a second map, with the same keys, which basically just holds the size of the list in an Integer, and get those values.

Here is my code:

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!testMap}" var="key">
        <apex:outputText value="{!listSizeMap[key]}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class TestController 
{
    public Map<String, List<String>> testMap {get;set;}
    public Map<String, Integer> listSizeMap {get;set;}

    public TestController()
    {
        listSizeMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        testMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        testMap.put('test1', new List<String>{'1', '2'});
        testMap.put('test2', new List<String>());

        for(String key : testMap.keySet())
        {
            listSizeMap.put(key, testMap.get(key).size());
        }
    }
}
```

**Map Explanation** (old answer, but perhaps useful for other people)

You can't do a `.size` on a value of the map.

You try to get a single value from the map by adding the square brackets with the variable M `{!attributeWrapper.mapAllAttributesLabel[M].size}` which is basically equal to `mapAllAttributesLabel.get(M);` in apex.

if you want to get the size of your map just do `{!attributeWrapper.mapAllAttributesLabel.size}` which is equal to `mapAllAttributesLabel.size();` in apex.

with the apex repeat, you loop over the keys in your map, and the var set by var="M" defines the current key in your loop. Each time you do mapAllAttributesLabel[M] you get the value of that key in your map.

Comment: correct. i will get value each time by using  mapAllAttributesLabel[M]. and as value is it self a list and i what that list size. i want to get size of a value list associated with a key. Is there not a way to get size of value list?

Comment: aha! well, theoretically i think that should work then, could be that it's not possible with Visualforce. Let me test it out.

Comment: I just tested it out, and I dont think its possible to do it directly from visualforce, I tried to fiddle around trying to get it to work with an <apex:param> but unfortunately that didn't work either, what I ended up doing, and got it to work will be added to my answer.